# Add a validation which is not related to the form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to add a validation on a form. My actual form works, here it is:

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'subject' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Do something if everything is OK.
}
```

Now, I want to check if the user is "active" too. So something like:

```
\Auth::user()->isActive();
```

And return an error **with the other validation errors** if the user is not active.

Can I append something to the validator that has no relation with the form itself? I mean I want to add an error to the other errors if the user is not active.

Comment: What will be output of Auth::user()->isActive()?

Comment: @Muthu17 "Your account is not active, please activate it" or something like that

Comment: You can use https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules or https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation for it. If you choose to use form request then you can add an after hook function to it.

Comment: My suggestion is do not allow the user to store function before activate or else use middleware and redirect them to activation page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is only validating the request variable (first argument of validate() function). So you will have to put someting in the request to validate it. It applies the rules to the object/array given.

```
$request->is_active = Auth::user()->isActive();
$this->validate($request, [
    'subject' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
    'is_active' => true //or whatever rule you want
]);
```

Anyways, I never tried that so not sure it will work. The usual way is to do an if

```
if ( !Auth::user()->isActive() ) {
    return redirect->back()->withErrors(['account' => 'Your account is not active, please activate it']);
}

//continue here
```